# scroll bar is not loading on ipad when click on a select button

Tags: iphone, css, scrollbar

we have a page with a search box. search box is displayed using an iframe. on that search box, we have multiple select boxes.there is a select tab to select children.if user select the option for "more", another dynamic div will be displayed.  when this div is loaded, scroll bar is displayed so user can scroll down to add more. this is working fine on all browsers, but scroll bar is not displaying when we test that page using ipad or iphone.

what is the reason for thsi and how can we solve this?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check outer div property.
may be in css used overflow:hidden;

You need to remove it,
If possible please share URL,